Problems to update and delete an object nested within an array
I am trying to delete one of the objects that are inside the folders folder, I am a beginner in Mongo and I am not very sure how to implement it, I tried the following code and it is ok but the object continues to appear.
This is the object:
{
    _id: ObjectId('6631499d751293d1ac1e7f45'),
    label: 'Test Template',
    folders: [
      {
        fld_name: 'Test Folder One',
        formfield: [],
        _id: ObjectId('663174af751293d1ac1e7f49')
      },
      {
        fld_name: 'Test Folder Two',
        formfield: [],
        _id: ObjectId('663174c7751293d1ac1e7f4c')
      },
      {
        fld_name: 'Test Folder Three',
        formfield: [],
        _id: ObjectId('66317504751293d1ac1e7f4f')
      }
    ],
    createdAt: ISODate('2024-04-30T19:42:21.751Z'),
    updatedAt: ISODate('2024-05-01T06:13:06.192Z')
  }

I want to delete an object that is inside the folders array

I want to delete an object that is inside the folders array. but when I implement the code it tells me ok but it does not eliminate it
export const deleteFolder = async (req: Request, res: Response) => {
  try {
    const query = { _id: req.params.id };
    const deleteFolder = { $pull: { "folders.$[].formfield": { _id: query } } };
    const result = await Template.updateOne(query, deleteFolder);
    console.log(result);
    res.status(201).json({ message: "Folder was deleted successfully!" });
  } catch (error) {
    console.error(error);
    res.status(500).json({ success: false, error: "Something went Wrong!" });
  }
};


You've given { _id: { _id: req.params.id } } as value... That duplicated _id at least doesn't seem right.

Agree with Trincot. But moreover: the first argument of updateOne is to filter entries based on that {_id: req.params.id} you provided. The second argument is about what to do with the filtered result. You are passing that same query to pull out from somewhere. But... It sure won't find it. Think about a building in New York.... Say {_id: req.params.id} is {_id: "109 E 42nd St"}.. Then once you arrived and inside of the Hyatt Hotel, you ask at the lobby to reach {_id: {_id: "109 E 42nd St"} } on a specific floor... Nothing happening here is quite good compared to real life. ;)
